# vba create a new sheet and change name

Tags: vba, excel

I am a VBA new user. My purpose is copy a existing worksheet to a new one. And then change the new worksheet name to a proper name. However, I got the VBA Error Message like,

vba runtime error 9 subscript out of range(at the line **Set new_ws =Active**...)

The VBA code will be the following; thanks in advance

```
Sub CreateWS()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim new_ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bus Voltage")
    ws.Name = "Bus Voltage_All"
    ws.Copy Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set new_ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bus Voltage_All(2)")
    new_ws.Name = "Bus Voltage"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you only run this code once?

Comment: I do not quite understand what do you mean. The code can be implemented with single run. Then, yes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you have an issue with a space.

Your line `Set new_ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bus Voltage_All(2)")`

Should be

`Set new_ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Bus Voltage_All (2)")`

Notice the space after _All?  You were missing that in your code.

A (potentially) helpful tidbit is that when you use the `.Copy` method, your new worksheet is automatically activated, so you can use this code instead (to avoid errors with the space):

```
ws.Copy Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
Set new_ws = ActiveSheet
```

And, on the topic of referencing sheets at all (though not directly related to your question), you can use something called the [CodeName](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm) to reference the sheet.

For example:

[image]

The CodeNames are Sheet1, Sheet2, etc.

The code:

```
Worksheets("Old Data").Activate
```

And

```
Sheet1.Activate
```

are equivalent.

The major benefit to referencing sheets this way is that if your worksheet name changes, your code won't break.

Comment: No problem!  I added extra information that I found useful in terms of referencing sheets in general just more as an FYI since you are a new VBA user.  If you found my answer to be helpful I'd appreciate if you'd click the check mark near the arrows to accept it as an answer.  Good luck in your VBA endeavors ^_^.

Comment: I will accept your answer. Unfortunately, the up button is grey-out...Because it said it needs 15+ reputation to do that. - - |||

Comment: Good answer. Would consider adding error handling in case that sheet name already existed (ie if code was run twice).